# Can't coerce out of range value with mongo aggregator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the aggregate but encounters a problem with a large number.

Schema

```
amount: Number
```

Input data when inserting

```
{ type: "Deposit", amount: 10000000000000000000000 },
{ type: "Withdraw", amount: 50000000000000000000000 },
```

stored as

```
{ type: "Deposit", amount: 1e+22 }
{ type: "Withdraw", amount: 5e+22 }
```

Next, I try to use the aggregator to match both types and convert withdraw amount to negative by multiplying by -1

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '$or': [
        {
          'event': 'Deposit'
        }, {
          'event': 'Withdraw'
        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'event': '$event', 
      'amount': {
        '$cond': {
          'if': {
            '$eq': [
              '$event', 'Deposit'
            ]
          }, 
          'then': '$amount', 
          'else': {
            '$multiply': ['$amount', -1]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

However, the problem **Can't coerce out of range value 1e+22 to long**. My question is, is there any other way to accomplish this with the aggregator or should I store the data different way to prevent it to become `...e+...` when the number exceeds the range.

I'm currently using MongoDB v4.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a resolved bug [SERVER-42756](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-42756) in MongoDB specific versions, I am not sure how it was affect,

You should try mongoose [Decimal128](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#what-is-a-schematype) type,

Schema:

```
amount: mongoose.Types.Decimal128
```

---

Second option: if you don't want to change type in your schema try, [$toDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDecimal/index.html) operator from MongoDB v4.0,

```
'$multiply': [{ $toDecimal: '$amount' }, -1]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Qby1xcoQ1B)

Answer (score 0):

For storing monetary amounts, use Decimal128 type. In general using floats for monetary amounts is a terrible idea.

Comment: What if the amount is stored in the object type in the schema? ie. Schema = { data: Object } and inside data variable we store { amount: 300....... }. How can I define the schema in this case?

Comment: @D.-SM how do you go about solving the issue (not sure is an issue really) from the returned value as an object with `$numberDecimal` when queried?

Comment: Please ask a new question.